# Try to attach to a process in debug mode fails

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I have 2 solutions. Solution1 output type is exe and solution2 output type is class library. I open both the solutions in separate VS2008 editors.

Debug solution1 by clicking on F5. Now the solution1.exe is running. In the solution2 click on Debug and Attach to process. Select Solution1.exe for attaching.

I get the error as **"Unable to attach to the process. A debugger is already attached."**. May i know what is the issue and how can I come out this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

This is happened because proces can have **only one** debugger attached like error says.

You can start your program without debuger (in vs start **without debuging**) and then attach debbuger from solution2, if pdb files are correct this should work.

Comment: Do I have any option of debugging both the solutions together?

Comment: unfortunately no.. if it's in separate solutions.